# Map duplicate entries in an list to a single value

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working on a program that can track employee performance over four different floors of a building. It takes a list of users and these users are mapped to a floor. Occasionally the same user may cover 2 or even 3 of the floors. When this happens I want the task to be credited to the user regardless of what floor they are on. An example of this is the following:

```
users = ['David','David','Noah','Jenny']
tasksCompleted = [5,5,4,6]



desiredOutput = [10,10,4,6]
```

In this case, the desired output is 10 for index 0 and 1 because 5 tasks were completed on the first two floors that were covered by 'David'

My question is how do I achieve this? I've been stuck on this problem for a few days, and I'm having trouble finding out the answer. I've only gotten serious about using Python about a month ago, and this may not even be the best way to go about this problem. Any help, or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the values in tasksCompleted always the same for a given user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
users = ['David','David','Noah','Jenny']
tasksCompleted = [5, 5, 4, 6]
totalCompleted = {user: 0 for user in users}
for user, task in zip(users, tasksCompleted):
    totalCompleted[user] += task
desiredOutput = [totalCompleted[user] for user in users]
print(desiredOutput)
```

prints

```
[10, 10, 4, 6]
```

Comment: `totalCompleted` can be simplified to `dict.fromkeys(users, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple loop with `zip`:

```
d = {}
for u,t in zip(users, tasksCompleted):
    d[u] = d.get(u,0) + t

out = [d[u] for u in users]
```

Output: `[10, 10, 4, 6]`

Intermediate `d`:

```
{'David': 10, 'Noah': 4, 'Jenny': 6}
```